# how to solve java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, resultset

```
public class SpreadsheetGenerator {
void dailyreport( Connection con) throws SQLException, IOException {
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from ssa_msg_daily");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from ssa_msg_daily");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("employe db");

        XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(1);
        XSSFCell cell;
        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("id");
        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue("Sender");
        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue("Service");
        cell = row.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue("Message_identifier");
        cell = row.createCell(5);
        cell.setCellValue("Date");
        cell = row.createCell(6);
        cell.setCellValue("Incoming");
        cell = row.createCell(7);
        cell.setCellValue("Outgoing");
        int i = 2;

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("Sender"));
            cell = row.createCell(3);
            cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("Service"));
            cell = row.createCell(4);
            cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("Message_identifier"));
            cell = row.createCell(5);
            cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getDate("Date"));
            cell = row.createCell(6);
            cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("Incoming"));
            cell = row.createCell(7);
            cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("Outgoing"));
            i++;
        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("exceldatabase.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("exceldatabase.xlsx written successfully");
    }
    }


}
```

here ssa_msg_daily contains blank or null values in the table,so
while compiling i am getting error as

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK

occurs @ XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
how can i handle this situation and
i am using the resultset to convert to spreedsheet  using apache poi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a classpath issue. You have a mix of versions of the Apache POI project on your classpath. This mix of versions is causing a newer version of one of the classes to try to talk to one of the older ones and they aren't compatible.

The solution is to check your classpath (so, if you're using maven, gradle, or some other dependency system, the chain of dependencies), and fix it up. Possibly it's as simple as running a 'clean' command on your build system.

NB: Your code is very bad style - don't put a ton of code in finally blocks. Furthermore, 99.9% of your paste is a red herring. This one-liner will cause your problem already:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

The rest is irrelevant.

Comment: <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: thanks that worked . really thankful for the advice

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you will try with "try" and "catch".

```
public class SpreadsheetGenerator {
void dailyreport( Connection con) throws SQLException, IOException {
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = null;
try {
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from ssa_msg_daily");
} catch (Exception e) {

} 
    //ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from ssa_msg_daily");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("employe db");

    XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(1);
    XSSFCell cell;
    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("id");
    cell = row.createCell(2);
    cell.setCellValue("Sender");
    cell = row.createCell(3);
    cell.setCellValue("Service");
    cell = row.createCell(4);
    cell.setCellValue("Message_identifier");
    cell = row.createCell(5);
    cell.setCellValue("Date");
    cell = row.createCell(6);
    cell.setCellValue("Incoming");
    cell = row.createCell(7);
    cell.setCellValue("Outgoing");
    int i = 2;

    if(resultSet!=null){
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getInt("id"));
        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("Sender"));
        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("Service"));
        cell = row.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("Message_identifier"));
        cell = row.createCell(5);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getDate("Date"));
        cell = row.createCell(6);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("Incoming"));
        cell = row.createCell(7);
        cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("Outgoing"));
        i++;
    }}

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("exceldatabase.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("exceldatabase.xlsx written successfully");
}
}
 

}
```

Comment: sry my mistake . i am getting error in XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

Comment: The problem cannot be fixed with code. This is not the answer and is not salvagable.

Comment: the error occurs at XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();